# Graphael pie chart error?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm adding these headers corresponding to my local system path

```
<script language="javascript" src="/js/graphael/raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/js/graphael/g.raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/js/graphael/g.pie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I'm getting JavaScript error like:

> Raphael is not defined    in g.raphael.js file

Answer (score 2):

latest version of g.raphael and raphael are not compatible with each other. They changed their API and never really bothered to document it properly

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the paths to the files are correct? You can inspect them using firebug, or add an alert statement to each of the files and verify that they are run.

Comment: i put alert on top and it display all the alerts, so i my paths are correct

Comment: Raphael.fn.g is undefined, Raphael is undefined im getting these 2 errord

Comment: i still having the same problem, any one knows why ? or how to debug this ?